# Oracle OCI - failing with ORA-12705 when running as another user

Tags: c, oracle, unix, oracle-call-interface, instantclient

I've got a C application using OCI to talk to a database.  I'm using the instant client method so there is no standalone Oracle installation on the server - just a couple of libraries that the application is linked against.

Normally, the application runs as user dai, and everything works just fine.  But if the application is run as another user (in group dai), it fails to run, reporting:

```
Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-12705
```

So I can imagine that this is a permissions error, but I'm not sure what files it is trying to access.  The permissions of the Oracle libraries are

```
dai:/dai/oracle/lib> ls -l
total 201872
-rwxrwxrwx   1 dai      dai        24719097 16 Feb 2009  libclntsh.a
-rwxrwxrwx   1 dai      dai         5972457 16 Feb 2009  libocci.a
-rwxrwxrwx   1 dai      dai        72651344 04 Jun 2010  libociei.so
```

As you can guess the main OCI libraries are statically linked, but there is one dynamically linked library (not sure why, but the AIX instantclient package came with these files...).  My LIBPATH looks OK from both users:

```
LIBPATH=/dai/oracle/lib
```

Which other permissions do I need to check?

EDIT: I have just tried running `truss` (AIX equivalent of Linux `strace`) to see what is happening.  I couldn't see it reading any unexpected files when running as the dai user.  Truss seemed to have problems tracing a set-uid program - permissions on the C application were set like this:

```
dai:/dai/bin> ls -l stats_backup
-rwsrwsr-x   1 dai      dai         6173358 Aug 12 10:08 stats_backup
```

So I did `chmod a-s` and tried again, and it now works!

So the program runs OK without the s-bit, but as soon as I put it back, it breaks again.  I can't run truss with the s-bit set, which makes it difficult to find out why this should be.  The program doesn't work in other circumstances without the s-bit set, so this isn't a viable solution, but hopefully a pointer to where the problem may be.

Comment: As many veteran users here on S.O. look only at messages tagged with their interests/specialties, you'll get more eyes on your problem if you change your aix tag to unix. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll give it a go!  In fact while asking around people at work, it turns out an eerily similar problem also exists on Solaris so whatever the problem is, it is likely not AIX specific.

Comment: It might related with the `oradiag` directory that is created by the ora client, it's name is `/home/yourname/oradiag_yourname`

Answer (score 0):

There are presumably some Oracle data files located somewhere that your other users don't have access to.  [According to Google, ORA-12705](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=ORA-12705&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) happens because the NLS data files (wherever they are) can't be accessed, or perhaps there is some environment variable issue.

Comment: As far as I am aware though, the relevant file is libociei.so.  The OCI stuff all works without this there, as long as I don't set NLS_LANG (and only use ASCII characters).  However the software is running in Spain so ASCII isn't a viable option.

Comment: You should include this info in your problem description. It seems  very germaine to your issue. Given that you have identified NLS_LANG as an issue, have you diffed the 2 user environments for other variables that may be throwing a spanner in the works? Good luck!